# Intel TXT is preventing me updating BIOS on a Toshiba Portege Z30

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I want to update my Toshiba Portege Z30-A to the latest BIOS.

Having downloaded the latest BIOS from the drivers page for my exact model from the Toshiba website, when I try to run the exe file, I get an error message:

> Intel TXT (Trusted Execution Technology) is enabled. BIOS cannot be updated while the Intel TXT is enabled

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable Intel TXT in the BIOS settings before you begin.

To enter the BIOS setup on a Portege Z30, you need to power on while holding the F2 key. On the Z30, this will enter the Toshiba Setup Utility (i.e., BIOS settings).

Select **Advanced**, then select **Trusted Execution Technology**. Set the toggle switch to 'disabled'. Exit with F10, and continue on to run the BIOS update exe you downloaded.

After the update has finished, go back into BIOS setup to enable TXT again.